# How to refresh a single item inside Repeater control using updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a social network website, the problem I'm facing here is that I used an update panel inside the repeater and I want to refresh the contents of the updatepanel when the user clicks on any linkbutton and ofcourse this updatepanel will be repeated foreach (div-post), but when I click on any linkbutton inside the repeater control and the updatepanel it doesn't refresh. How do I force it to refresh ?. Here is the code I'm using ...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
                                OnItemCommand="MyButtonCommandEvent">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="post">
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="postID_hidden" runat="server" 
                                            Value='<%# Eval("posts_ID") %>' />
                                        <div class="Thumb">
                                            <img src="thumbs/abdo_thumb.jpg"> </img></div>
                                        <span class="user"><%#Eval("poster_name")%>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="post-body">
                                            <p>
                                                <%#Eval("description")%>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="post-options" style=" height:22px; ">
                                            <span class="first"><%#Eval("post_date")%></span>
                                            <ul style="display:inline; list-style-type: none;">
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="tooltip">
                                                        Comments
                                                        <img class="tool-img" src="Images/comments.png"> : <%#Eval("comment_num") %> 
                                                        </img>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="tooltip">
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="like_linkbtn" runat="server" CommandName="Like" OnClick="Like_Click"><%#(Eval("name_like").ToString() == "") ? "Like" : Eval("name_like")%></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        <img class="tool-img" src="images/likes.png"> : <%#Eval("like_counter") %>
                                                        </img></div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="tooltip">
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="hate_linkbtn" runat="server" CommandName="Hate"><%#(Eval("name_hate").ToString() == "") ? "Hate" : Eval("name_hate")%></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        <img class="tool-img" src="images/hate.png"> : <%#Eval("hate_counter") %>
                                                        </img></div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="finish">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

And the server side code

```
  protected void Like_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
  protected void MyButtonCommandEvent(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var postID = e.Item.FindControl("postID_hidden") as HiddenField;
        NewUser user = new NewUser();
        if (e.CommandName == "Like")
        {
            user.like_post(int.Parse(postID.Value), (int)Session["accountID"]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Hate")
            {
                user.hate_post(int.Parse(postID.Value), (int)Session["accountID"]);
            }
        }

      // repeater_databind();//This will refresh all the contents of the repeater(bad way)
    }
```

So as can see databind is not working for me because I want to refresh only one item in the repeater control and not the whole items, can anyone help me please ?

**Edit :** 
Problem solved by wrapping the whole repeater in another updatepanel and setting the trigger like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers> 
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Repeater1" EventName="MyButtonCommandEvent" /> 
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the `UpdateMode` propery of your update panel to `Conditional`

Comment: Well I did just now but it still don't refresh